# Can Azure.Identity be used with WindowsAzure.Storage?

Tags: authentication, azure-storage

Is it safe (from a protocol/compatibiltiy point of view) to retrieve an access token using `Azure.Identity` and use it with `WindowsAzure.Storage`?

I am working on an application which use `WindowsAzure.Storage` to communicate with Azure Storage (blobs+queues). Currently the application use Account Name/AccessKey to authenticate.

I want to migrate from using AccountName/Access Keys to use Managed Service Identity,  Interactive Browser Login or Certificate (depending on where the application is running). Main reason bing simplifying credential rotation.

I think the (deprecated) library `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` could be used to accomplish this, but I wonder if it's safe to use `Azure.Identity` to perform the retrieval of the authentication token instead. Microsoft recommends to use `Azure.Identity` with new applications, but this library seems to be primarily focused on the new Azure.* client SDK:s  (as opposed to `WindowsAzure.Storage` which I am using).

The below code works fine in a simple test, but I don't know if there would be any issues doing this:

```
var resourceId = "https://storage.azure.com/";

// Request access token via interactive browser
var browserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
var accessToken = await browserCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { resourceId + "/.default" }) { }
);

// Use the access token to access Azure Storage
var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken.Token);
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials,"<mystorageaccount>","core.windows.net", true);

var queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");
```

I know WindowsAzure.Storage is also deprecated and applications should upgrade to Azure.Storage, but it's not something I have to do a bit furher down the road (large application and the above has higher prio).

Comment: At some point your token will expire and your `TokenCredential` won't be able to renew it as you only provided it your single token. The `TokenCredential` class does have a constructor that allows you to add a function for renewal.